# Issues with calculating the determinant of a matrix

Tags: matlab, linear-algebra, matrix-inverse

I am trying to calculate the determinant of the inverse of a matrix. The inverse of the matrix exists. However, when I try to calculate the determinant of the inverse, it gives me Inf value in matlab. What is the reason behind this?

Comment: Perhaps your matrix is *very close* to singular.

Comment: What do you mean very close to singular

Comment: If it's very close to singular, then the determinant will be very close to zero, so the determinant of the inverse will be very large.  If the computation is limited by numerical precision, it could end up being infinity.

Comment: It's not singular because its inverse exists

Comment: I realise that.  But it might be close enough for numerical precision to dominate.

Comment: I have just realized that my diagonal elements are very small. That's why when I calculate the determinant it is almost equal to 0 and matlab shows it as 0. The diagonal elements are in the range of 0.025 and my matrix is of size 50,000x50,000.

Comment: In that case, problem solved!  You should now close this question.

Comment: Actually I have a diagonal matrix of size 331x331. Out of them around 171 of them have value in the range 0.0020 and the rest have higher value from 1.24,6.35 to 500 as well. Shouldn't it have a determinant?

Comment: I think googling matrix identities could help you out here. The determinant of a diagonal matrix is the product of the elements along the diagonal. The determinant of the inverse is the reciprocal of that.   If you are worried about numerical inaccuracies, you could scale your matrix by a factor. I agree with closing the question at this point.

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: given `A = inv(B)`, then `det(A)==Inf` may have two explanations:

1. an overflow during the numerical computation of the determinant,
2. one or more infinite elements in `A`.

In the first case your matrix is badly scaled so that `det(B)` may underflow and `det(A)` overflow. Remember that `det(a*B) == a^N * det(B)` where `a` is a scalar and `B` is a `N` times `N` matrix.

In the second case (i.e. `nnz(A==inf)>0`) matrix `B` may be "singular to working precision".

PS:

A matrix is nearly singular if it has a large condition number. (A small determinant has nothing to do with singularity, since the magnitude of the determinant itself is affected by scaling.).

A matrix is singular to working precision if it has a zero pivot in the Gaussian elimination: when computing the inverse, matlab has to calculate `1/0` which returns `Inf`.

In fact in Matlab overflow and zero-division exceptions are not caught, so that, according to IEEE 754, an `Inf` value is propagated.